# How to integrate instamojo payment gateway in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

I am new to integrating payment gateway in ASP.Net. So I want to know the steps to do for integrating that to my ASP.Net web app. I have downloaded the C# wrapper from Github provided as a reference by Instamojo. But my mind is null/NIL cause I don't know what and how to do. So I need someone to shed some light on this topic. I tried searching the internet, unfortunately no results..

I tried nothing so far. I just have my ASP.Net web app and the C# .NET wrapper (That is what they call it as..) with me.

Comment: all payment gateway provide example code and documentation. just follow the documentation with your payment gateway simply.  also they provide test transactions method so just go ahead!! if you stuck somewhere they provide support also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Integrating Instamojo payment gateway in asp.net c#*

I'll list it in steps:

Step 1 : There are two accounts provided by Instamojo

- Live / Production account - www.Instamojo.com
- Test account - test.instamojo.com
  so create an account in test.instamojo.com and go to the dashboard and create your new test credentials as shown below [clientID and client Secret will be provided]

[image]

Step 2 : Go to https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-csharp and download the c# wrapper [filename] from there and extract it and open

Steo 3 : Just copy the InstamojoAPI folder from the downloaded/extracted folder and paste it in your project desired

[image]

Step 4 : Copy the code unser the section named Create new payment order under payments API in the github link - https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-csharp and copy that in your project in a new form/file

Step 5 : After copying, in your code Replace client id with your test client id, client secret with your test client secret, endpoint with the following url : https://test.instamojo.com/v2/ and authendpoint with the following url : https://test.instamojo.com/oauth2/token/

```
Instamojo objClass = InstamojoImplementation.getApi( “[client_id]”, “[client_secret]”, “[endpoint]”, “[auth_endpoint]”);
```

Step 6 : You have to provide these parameters as shown below
[image]

Step 7 : Then find the below code in your project and replace the messagebox with response.redirect like below

[image]

Thats it you are good to go. Fire the run button and see the results as below

First your localhost home page will fire. you have to create a form like this below
[image]

Then on pay button click this should appear
[image]

Then..this.. [Your test/sandbox acnt details in here - https://support.instamojo.com/hc/en-us/articles/208485675-Test-or-Sandbox-Account]
[[image]][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ehJ.png)

then finally
 [image]

then after payment it should redirect to your redirection_url as specified before.
like this

```
objPaymentRequest.redirect_url = “redirect_url”;
```

Thats it.. Happy coding